# ionic 3 ion-radio checked when string is equal to something

Tags: ionic-framework, soap, ionic3

I'm currently working on a client page that reads from a SOAP some values and I'm trying to check a ion-radio if the value read from the call is equal to m or f. This is my code:

```
<ion-col col-2 style="margin-top:1%">
      <ion-label>
        <strong class="sexClass">{{'longRegister.sex' | translate }}</strong>
      </ion-label>
      <div radio-group formControlName="gender" style="margin-top:-10%;margin-left:23%" [(ngModel)]="customer.SESSO">
        <ion-radio color="dark" value="F" checked="customer.SESSO == 'f'"></ion-radio>
        <span>
          <strong style="position: absolute;margin-top: -1%; margin-left: 2%;font-size:16px">F</strong>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div radio-group formControlName="gender" style="margin-left: 47%;margin-top: -10%" [(ngModel)]="customer.SESSO">
        <ion-radio color="dark" value="M" checked="customer.SESSO == 'm'"></ion-radio>
        <span>
          <strong style="position: absolute;margin-top: -1%;margin-left: 4%;font-size:16px">M</strong>
        </span>
      </div>
    </ion-col>
```

My DB table that I read is like this: [SESSO] char NULL,

Thanks in advance.
Traian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using `[value]` and  `[checked]`, now my code looks like this:

```
<div radio-group formControlName="gender" style="margin-top:-3%;margin-left:23%" [(ngModel)]="customer.SESSO">
        <ion-radio color="dark" [value]="F" [checked]="customer.SESSO == 'f' "></ion-radio>
        <span>
          <strong style="position: absolute;margin-top: -1%; margin-left: 2%;font-size:16px">F</strong>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div radio-group formControlName="gender" style="margin-left: 47%;margin-top: -10%" [(ngModel)]="customer.SESSO"
      class="radio-privacy in-middle">
        <ion-radio color="dark" [value]="M" [checked]="customer.SESSO == 'm' "></ion-radio>
        <span>
          <strong style="position: absolute;margin-top: -1%;margin-left: 4%;font-size:16px">M</strong>
        </span>
      </div>
```